# Hide/Show status bar at runtime

Tags: android, android-theme, android-statusbar

I want to have a fullscreen app, that hides the status bar in `onCreate`, and then at some point, when the user opens the Options Menu, I want to show the status bar. Then, when the Options Menu is closed, to hide the status bar again.

Currently I am unable to achieve this, as changes to status bar can only be done before adding content to the Activity, so trying to do it like this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

throws this exception

```
09-01 12:37:19.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2737): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.bla.blabla/com.bla.blabla.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

Can this be achieved at all?

EDIT: I know that when you make it for first time, the code must be called before `setContentView`, **THAT IS CLEAR ENOUGH**, I want to know if it's possible for these changes to be made later at runtime, when the user interacts with the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Immersive Full-screen mode (available on 4.4+). Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html).

Answer (score 0):

call before **setContentView**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activitylayout);
```

like

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activitylayout);
```